# How does the TOR-browser-bundle work and how can I make it work

Tags: internet, browser, privacy

I'm currently using the Tor browser-bundle. I know, that it uses the TOR-software.

But I'd really like to know, how the browser-bundle and TOR basically works and how I'm able to install it properly on different operation-system.

Comment: See also the new beta Stack Exchange site [tor.se].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## How does the TOR-network work?

In general as seen in the picture, it uses different random nodes to send your traffic through to completely anonymize your traffic which is sent straight through your browser. **Traffic through third-party plugins, flash for example, won't be anonymized.**

### Easy to understand explanation

The TOR-network uses "nodes" to pass your traffic through. Without TOR, a visit of a website would be direct.

1. User **Alice** sends a request to **Bob**.
2. The requested server responds to the request and gives back the information.

With TOR, it's a bit more complicated.

1. User **Alice** wants to open a website.
2. The TOR-client gets a list of Tor-nodes from a directory-server **Dave**.

   [image]
3. The TOR-Client now picks randomly a path to the target, through these nodes. As you see in the picture, the whole way to the target is encrypted. Only the way from the last node to the target isn't encrypted. So it's not possible to reproduce, from which computer the request came and where the request originally started.

   [image]
4. If you reconnect to the exact same server, than the nodes will be choosen randomly again. So no way is the same as the last one.

   [image]

## What is the TOR-browser-bundle

This bundle comes with a browser, that has TOR integrated in it.
I recommend this bundle, because:

- you don't need to install any software. Just download the tool and run it to start the Tor-browser.
- it is compatible for any gui-operating-system

  - Windows
  - Mac OS X
  - Linux
- it's easy to use, also for "newbies".

### How to install and use the bundle

#### Windows

1. Download the bundle from the tor-project-website. **[Download](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#downloads)**
2. Extract the ZIP-file
3. Open the `Tor-Browser`-folder.
4. Start the Tor browser by clicking on the `Start Tor Browser`-Application.
5. The vidalia-window will apear. *Please wait until the browser opens*.

   [image]
6. A new Firefox window should appear.
7. Every website that you will now visit, will be visited completely anonymous through the TOR-network.
8. If you close the firefox-browser, TOR will automatically stop and will shut down. To restart the TOR-browser, just click on the `Start Tor Browser`-Application again.

#### Mac OS X

1. Download the bundle from the tor-project-website. **[Download](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#downloads)**
2. Open the file. You don't have to unzip it, because OSX will automatically open it.
3. Click on the `TorBrowser_your-Language` application to launch the TOR-browser.

   [image]
4. It will take a while, but after vidalia is ready, a new firefox-browser will be launched.

#### Linux

1. Download the bundle from the tor-project-website which fits your architecture. **[Download](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#downloads)**
2. To extract the file, use the following command, but you have to exchange the `YOURLANGUAGE` with the language shown in the filename of your language:

   - 32 bit-version

     ```
     tar -xvzf tor-browser-gnu-linux-i686-2.3.25-13-dev-YOURLANGUAGE.tar.gz
     ```
   - 64 bit-version

     ```
     tar -xvzf tor-browser-gnu-linux-x86_64-2.3.25-13-dev-YOURLANGUAGE.tar.gz
     ```
3. Open the TOR-directory

   ```
   cd tor-browser_YOURLANGUAGE
   ```
4. To run the browser-bundle, type in the following command:

   ```
   ./start-tor-browser
   ```

### Conclusion

The bundle is very good to anonymize your browsing. It is a 99.99% safe way to be anonymous at the internet. Nobody was able yet to decrypt/hack the TOR-network.

I highly recommend it.

Comment: Just a side note: As much as TOR is making your traffic hidden, this will not stop side-channel attack such as: Someone sees the site you're visiting from behind you/over the shoulder, or if someone has physical access to your computer or if someone has managed to remotely access your PC (nothing is safe after that). Tor creates anonymity yes, but if security is utmost important, you can't let your guard down.

Comment: Many thx for your input. I've added this to the post.